# Random character being added in C

Tags: c

I basically have this

```
void process(char * str){

int z = 0;
char * copy = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));

printf("Original: %s\n", str);
for(z = 0; z<strlen(str);z++){
    char tempone = tolower(str[z]);
    copy[z] = tempone;
}

z++; copy[z] = '\0';
printf("Copy: %s\n", copy);

 }
```

But the results I get are:

```
 Original: If
Copy: ifu
```

When I want:

```
Original: If
Copy: if
```

This error only happens to certain text words, so I'm not sure what the error is. I'm just getting used to C so I'm not sure if I'm missing something basic. However, what I wrote seemed pretty simple, but I keep getting "ifu" as a copy even tho I initially entered "if". The string length of str is 2

Comment: Minor: Let `size_t L = strlen(str);`.  The repetitive calls to `strlen()` are very inefficient for code calls `strlen()` `L` times.  Better to determine it once and then use it in `malloc()` and `for (...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that extra

`z++;`

sentence after the loop. This is because `z` is incremented in the last iteration, and after that the condition `z<strlen(str)` fails, when z == strlen(str) is true.

That extra letter you are getting:

Original: If

Copy: if`u`

Is just garbage in the memory. Because if you increment `z` after the loop, the value is not within the array's dimension anymore.

So, I believe this should work:

```
void process(char * str){

  int z = 0;
  char * copy = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));

  printf("Original: %s\n", str);
  for(z = 0; z<strlen(str);z++){
    char tempone = tolower(str[z]);
    copy[z] = tempone;
  }

  copy[z] = '\0';
  printf("Copy: %s\n", copy);

 }
```

Assume the simplest examples:

Original: I

Copy: i

1. You will do a malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+1)). Noticed that [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) does not include the null character.
2. `for(z = 0; z < 1; z++)` -> This will be executed once. Because when trying to iterate for the second time, you will increment `z` from `0` to `1`, so the condition `z < 1` will be `1 < 1` which is false.
3. Outside the loop you want to put a `'\0'` in the `copy[1]`, not in `copy[2]`. This is why you really don't need that `z++` outside the loop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope it still returns ifu

Comment: did you try cleaning and rebuilding your project? @AbhishekSaha

Comment: @AbhishekSaha I have just tried that code, look at [this code](http://pastebin.com/vqzwvLMT) and use an online [C compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the solution. I used strcpy before the for loop, as seen here.

```
  int z = 0;
char * copy = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));
strcpy(copy, str);
for(z = 0; z<strlen(str);z++){
    *(copy+z) = tolower(*(copy+z));
}
```

Why this worked and the other code didn't, I have no idea.

Comment: that is not the way to solve it, that works because strcpy will copy the '\0' character to your 'copy' variable. [Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) "Copies the C string pointed by source into the array pointed by destination, including the terminating null character (and stopping at that point)."